# Angular parse html string from a contenteditable field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, html-parsing

I got a contenteditable div field where user can type text, which supports emotion icons and mentions (tagging user with @). I've used mentio for angular which basicly replaces the "code" the user has written with HTML, i.e. if the user writes ":-)" then it will be replaced with a img tag with src to the smiley icon. Tagging a user will wrap the tagged name with span tags that has a class for styling and data-attribute for user id.

I want to manipulate the string when I post the message to the server and remove the html code mentio has added. The smileys should be converted back to its code (i.e. ":-)") and mentions should be in this format:  [id of person:name of person] (i.e. [101:John Doe]).

Example input:

```
Some text <img src="thumbsUp.png" height=20 width=20> for <span class="selected" data-fullName="John Doe" data-userId="101">@JohnDoe</span>
```

Desired output that the input should be converted to:

```
Some text :thumbsUp: for [101:John Doe]
```

The question is what is the best solution to go about this and some example code would also really help.

Comment: I ended up parsing the HTML with regex but this is considered less then the most optimal solution. For example does Firefox switch places of height and width so your regex has to take this in account. So I'm interested in knowing if there's any better solutions for it

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, do you have anything to add since ?

Comment: We ended up dropping contenteditable and went using normal input instead. The WYSIWYG feature would have been nice but it was causing us too much headache to be worth it. We solved the mention and smileys by using "code" for them like in stackoverflow. So @name for mention and :smiley: for smileys.

Comment: @RVandersteen did you find a solution?